# Removing from the list with button click

Tags: c#, list

I'm printing out items from the list each to the label, and a button nearby for removing them from the list. The removal button doesn't seem to work.

```
private void cart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    krepselioPanel.Visible = !krepselioPanel.Visible;
    krepselioPav.Visible = !krepselioPav.Visible;

    int i = 0;
    double s = 0;

    foreach (Patiekalas preke in prekes)
    {
        Label prekiulist = new Label();

        prekiulist.Location = new Point(0, 26 * i);
        prekiulist.Text = preke.GetPatiekalas() + " | " + preke.GetKaina() + "€";
        prekiulist.Size = new Size(200, 20);
        krepselioPanel.Controls.Add(prekiulist);
        s += Convert.ToDouble(preke.GetKaina());

        Button removeButton = new Button();
        removeButton.Text = "x";
        removeButton.Location = new Point(200, 26 * i);
        removeButton.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 9);
        removeButton.Size = new Size(20, 22);
        removeButton.Click += removeButton_Click;
        removeButton.Tag = preke;
        krepselioPanel.Controls.Add(removeButton);
        i++;
    }


    Label suma = new Label();
    suma.Location = new Point(krepselioPanel.Right - 140, 0);
    suma.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 13);
    suma.Text = "Total: " + s + "€";
    suma.Size = new Size(130, 25);
    krepselioPanel.Controls.Add(suma);

}


private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    Patiekalas preke = (Patiekalas)b.Tag;
    prekes.Remove(preke);
    cart_Click(sender, e);
    cart_Click(sender, e);
}
```

}

Just for the interest sake I changed the functions removeButton_Click line

> prekes.Remove(preke);

to

> prekes.Add(preke);

and this creates a new entry to the list but removal doesn't work however.

Comment: Do you clear the controls from the panel at some point? Now it seems the code just adds controls to the panel but doesn't remove the old ones. Did you check with a debugger that `prekes` really still contains the item even after removal?

Comment: Case closed. Thank you very much.

Comment: you should try to remove as krepselioPanel.Controls.Remove( "yourControl" );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't seem to remove the previous controls from the panel so each time the controls are added new ones are created. If you have only one item in the cart then the next time nothing seems to happen, nothing added nor removed, but if there's multiple items they will start to multiply.

So remove the controls from the panel and then add new ones and the item will disappear.